# I can't seem to update a gem I made or even delete it from the app - app still uses it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have an app which is using a new gem I've been making (first attempt ever to make a gem) and it doesn't matter what I do I can't update the gem in my rails app. I've built the gem, then installed it (e.g. `gem install ./youtube_query-1-0-6.gem`). When I view it in `irb` it works as expected. I then proceed to register it with rubygems, this works successfully (again, it seems). So, when I add it to my Gemfile in my rails app and hit `bundle install` (or `bundle update` then `bundle install` if I've change the version) I can see it has installed the latest version. But, when I view my rails app page that uses the gem and debug the data that is returned it doesn't change and is inconsistent with what I'm seeing in `irb`.

Next, I try to just return something completely different so I know that it has updated - `return "hi"`. When I follow the steps above so I can see "hi" being returned in irb, then proceed until `bundle update`/ `bundle install` (confirming that the "hi" version is shown) then debug what the gem returns - still, no change in my app.

Finally, I do `bundle uninstall youtube_query` and tell it to delete all versions. This seems to work. But still my page returns old data - even though I've apparently uninstalled it. I've even tried removing it from the Gemfile then `bundle install` and STILL it works.

OK, my understanding is obviously wrong of how this may work. Is there anything I should know about gems that clearly I don't? How can I most importantly update properly the gem in rubygems and my Rails app. Thanks.

http://rubygems.org/gems/youtube_query (my gem)

Comment: How do you start your server?

Comment: Yes, that's a good point, this can often happen if you forget to restart your server.

Comment: I see! I thought I'd be clever and have another terminal window with the server running while another I could run things like bundle etc. Maybe not a great idea then, didn't realise I had to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Having different terminal windows open **is** useful, you would have just needed to switch to the one running the server to stop & restart it.  I always have lots of tabs open: server, console, my "main" one in the project folder, mysql, a console on the server with ssh, etc.